# Ubuntu doesn't load after intalling it alongside Windows 10 on Dell G7 7700

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, busybox

It's been a while, hope y'all are doing great.
So I had a day off from work today and decided to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Dell G7 7700, and as expected, everything didn't go well.
First, I created a 200GB partition on Windows before booting from my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS flash drive. Then Ubuntu complained about Intel RST and I had to switch Storage SATA from Raid to AHCI in the UEFI. After that, Ubuntu complained about Bitlocker so I had to turn that off in Windows. Anyways, I was finally able to complete Ubuntu installation by selecting "Install alongside Windows".
And then, I re-switched Storage SATA from AHCI back to Raid in the UEFI. Cuz otherwise Windows won't launch.
So now my computer boots with GRUB and I can choose Windows and it seems to work fine, whereas when I select Ubuntu it doesn't load Ubuntu but sends me this:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing Modules (cat /proc/modules; ls/dev)
ALERT! UUID=46587d8e-826d-4828-865f-5c4d809b1981 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

But that doesn't ring a bell to me so I ran Boot-repair with my Ubuntu flash-drive and it gave me this:
[Boot-Repair on Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QmR4Ys8xRw/)

So I am a little confused and would like some help to solve this problem.

Thank you very much,

Harp

Comment: This reads like a classic case of not being prepared. [Dell’s guide for dual-booting outlines these issues](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000131253/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en), and the documentation from Canonical regarding [Intel RST](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/) and [SecureBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) is linked to in a lot of online walk-throughs for people trying to run Linux alongside Windows10. This would be a good time to examine which features you need from both OSes, and set a common BIOS config 

Comment: Ok I have seen these tutorials and that's why I switched Intel RST and Secure Boot off. Maybe I shouldn't have installed ubuntu alongside, but rather select something else instead...